# Possibilities to short if-conditions in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, conditional-statements, short

if I want to short this if condition

```
if (x) {
    x = false;
} else {
    x = true;
}
```

i use the following code:

```
x = !x;
```

But what if I want to short this code? Is there a way to do that? If yes, how?

```
if (x) {
  method_1();
} else {
  method_2();
}
```

Comment: That won't "shorten" anything bytecode-wise; and even in the first case, the JVM may be smart enough to turn the first code into the second anyway. Nothing to be gained.

Comment: I can't imagine nothing smaller than `x = !x`.

Comment: Depends on what your methods are doing. But as for given set of codes, you can't shorten it more.

Comment: You gain in readability of course.

Comment: @amahfouz Any tweaking to that code, to gain readibility, would hardly improve readability. Sometimes we do more sins in attempt to do less or none.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ? : statement

```
x ? method_1() : method_2()
```

And sometimes, it is more readable to split it into multiple lines like this:

```
isSomethingTrue 
   ? method_1() 
   : method_2()
```

*Edit

To be precise, as others have commented, you need to assign the return value to some variable. So the bit of code would actually look like this:

```
someVar = isSomethingTrue 
   ? method_1() 
   : method_2()
```

which means you cannot do this with void methods.

Comment: I don't think this will work. In conditional expressions `B` and `C` part should not be void expression.

Comment: Not really. Try it out.

Comment: That won't even compile; you need to have a valid expression returning a value.

Comment: Yes, and why did you assume that these methods are void?! They could be returning an int or a boolean.

Comment: @Apurva Not exactly. There are restrictions for usage in conditional operator. You can't do: `bool-expr ? Sysout("hello") : Sysout("there")`, which you can do that using `if-else`.

Comment: Yes, right. I edited the answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I like amahfouz's answer.  Just want to add to it that you can persist the short by using lambdas.  This would prevent having to check the condition every time... making the short permanent.

```
public class TestLambdas {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    Function<String, String> myMethod;
    Function<String, String> myMethod_1 = (String y) -> {
        return y;
    };
    Function<String, String> myMethod_2 = (String y) -> {
        return y.trim();
    };

    public TestLambdas(boolean x) {
        myMethod = x
                ? myMethod_1
                : myMethod_2;

    }

}
```

So now you can call `myMethod()` without having to check the condition.

Answer (score -2):

```
 x=!x; is a good logic :)
```

You can use selection statement

```
 x = x==true?false:true;
```

Comment: How is it even better than `x = !x`? Moreover, that possesses a high level of unreadability.

Comment: it is not better than x =!x but what if you need to execute a number of statements on checks? x=!x is a very simple statement and readable statement..

Comment: Then I'll go with simple `if-else` statement, rather than convoluting the code with conditional expressions like those. First thing, you should not do boolean comparisons - `x == true` should almost always be written as `x`. Second, you can't execute any other statements in condition statements.. So that won't solve the purpose you're targetting at.

Comment: of-course that is very true..x=!x is not my solution, that is what  he has done..I just praised his logic..may I know what is your point here?

Comment: My point is, your answer is not adding any value to the question.